# Messed layout in "htop"

Tags: linux, command-line, opensuse, htop

I'm currently using openSUSE Tumbleweed (with KDE Plasma 5, if that matters).

I use `htop` to monitor system resources, and lately I get a messed layout, especially on the topmost area of the screen. The information is not easily readable, and it is not that useful in this state.

[image]

**How can I solve this?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was caused by ncurses.

To resolve this, I had to add the following line to my `~/.bashrc`:

```
export TERM=linux
```

[Reference on openSUSE forums.](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/527310-broken-layout-in-htop?p=2839240)

Comment: With `TERM=linux` I get font problems instaed. A value of `xterm-color` worked for me.

Comment: [`TERM=xterm-256color` seems a more modern solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/614714/349837)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by adding an alias for `htop` in `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
alias htop='TERM=xterm-color htop'
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps resetting config to default will help:

```
mv ~/.config/htop/htoprc{,.bak}
rm ~/.config/htop/htoprc
touch ~/.config/htop/htoprc
```

Try htop afterwards. If it didn't fix it you can restore your old config file:

```
mv -f ~/.config/htop/htoprc.bak ~/.config/htop/htoprc
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Which version of htop do you have? And do other ncurses-based programs function normally (like iftop, ncdu, ...)?

Comment: I have version 2.0.2

Comment: Can you check in settings which bar is active? 
F2 -> Left Column

The default is CPUs (1/1)

Comment: I have CPUs, Memory and Swap

Comment: I can't get my htop messed up like yours but I don't have anything with Plasma 5. Is it wonky in a tty (ctrl+alt+f2) as well?

Comment: No, on a tty it works correctly